# Google Finance API Still works?

Tags: google-finance-api

I still can obtain some data from finance google API using links like:
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG
Is that fine? Or it's will be closed soon?

But here is https://developers.google.com/finance/?csw=1
Google says: "The Google Finance APIs are no longer available. Thank you for your interest."